# How do i get amount of traffic consumed by browser from Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I tried to use this API

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

and sum up Content-Length fields, but they seem to be missing all the time. Is there any workable way to do it?

```
 chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(data) {
    console.log('Got request!', data);
    var size = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.responseHeaders.length; i++) {
        var header = data.responseHeaders[i];
        if (header.name === 'Content-Length') {
            size += parseInt(data.responseHeaders[i].value);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (size > 0) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            msg: 'traffic',
            amount: size
        }, function(resp) {})
    }
}, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, ["responseHeaders"]);
```

Result is that Content-Length header is always missing.

Thanks!

Comment: More data needed to continue, what is Content-Length and your code.

Comment: Added code snippet...

Comment: To be fair, your code is buggy to begin with. Your `break` is unconditional, so you at most look at the very first header.

Comment: right. stupid typo. corrected. in fact, i logged all headers, there is really no Content-Length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, but **`webRequest` API certainly doesn't provide this kind of information.**

Since, indeed, most of the time the server just pushes the content out without telling in advance how big it is, the only point where that information would be available is at the `onCompleted` event.

A quick look through [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onCompleted) shows no such information.

In general, `webRequest` shows a more abstract version of what is happening than what the network stack is actually doing (consuming). So it's not appropriate for the job.

To further drive this point home, here's a quote from the docs, which is partially related:

> Note that the web request API presents an abstraction of the network stack to the extension. Internally, one URL request can be split into several HTTP requests (for example to fetch individual byte ranges from a large file) or can be handled by the network stack without communicating with the network. For this reason, the API does not provide the final HTTP headers that are sent to the network. For example, all headers that are related to caching are invisible to the extension.
>
> The following headers are currently not provided to the `onBeforeSendHeaders` event. This list is not guaranteed to be complete nor stable.
>
> - ...
> - Content-Length
> - ...

---

**I don't think there's any reasonable approach for this.** `chrome://net-internals/#bandwidth` shows the data, but it's not exposed via an API (and you can't access that page from an extension).

It *might* be possible to get an approximation for a specific page via either a Dev Tools extension (having access to network events) or `chrome.debugger` API (same data through a different interface). But it would only work in a "reload this page to see stats" scenario and, again, will be more abstract than what actually happens on network level.